# UITableView not displaying content unless scrolling, or touching cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have 2 different UITableViews displaying posts that users are able to post on the app. I am using the Parse Framework to get that information on the cloud.

After working on my first TableView, it works just fine, so I recycled that code and I modified it so it works with a different UITableView that is displaying data from a different table on the database.

The first UITableView works just as expected, but the second one is not, even though the code is pretty much the same, the only thing that changes is the table where it's getting its data from.

Here's the code I'm using for getting the data from the cloud and displaying on the app:

```
@IBAction func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    findTimelineData.orderByAscending("createdAt")

    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects!{
                let post:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(post)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //return # of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //# of elements in the timeLineData array
    return timelineData.count
}


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! TableViewCell

    let post:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject

    cell.postTextView.alpha = 0
    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.postTextView.text = post.objectForKey("content") as! String

    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt!)

    // to get username from the post
    var showUsername:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    //the objectID is the same as the user in the two different tables
    showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId!!)

    showUsername.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            let user = (objects as! [PFUser]).last
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user!.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.postTextView.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

any ideas of what's going on? I already tried other posts on here, but nothing has been able to fix this issue.

[image: Cells in UITable]
[image: Cells in debugger]

Comment: You have to find your objects in view did load. get the data > fill the array and load it to the cells.

Comment: I am doing that in the `loadData()` function, and I call it in the `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: You are again finding the object in the cellforrow `showUsername.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{`

Comment: When you are about to show the data in your second tableview call 
`reloadData` in its swift syntax. I dont really know what that is.

Comment: Then what do you suggest @AshishKakkad? I keep on playing with the code but I cannot seem to get it to display all of the content like its supposed to

Comment: I have two different classes for the 2 different TableViews that I have, since they are both getting data from different tables from Parse.com, I didn't want to mix them into only one class @SahebRoy but the `reloadData()` it's there in my `loadData()` function and it's called in `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: call loadData whenever a new data is inserted or you are about to show the other tableview if data is not loaded.

Comment: I tried that, and it crashed the app every time I go to the TableView @SahebRoy

Comment: you mentioned that there are 2 tableview, but the `loadData()` function has only 1 tableview component (data) which is assigned. and loadData() isnt parameterised. Maybe the cause of the crash is that you want to show data for table2 but you are calling reload on table1 when table1 is already nil.

Comment: I have two different tableViews with two different classes. 
So basically, this code I submitted is the same one for my other tableView. So tableView1 and tableView2, are linked to individual classes, each of them handling a different table from Parse.com. In other words, each of the tableViews has it's own class, that handles different data from the could, if that makes sense @SahebRoy so the class for tableView2 only affects tableView2, and the class for tableView1, only affects tableView1

Comment: plz post the action method form the base class from where you are switching the tableviews.

Comment: @SahebRoy I figured out what was wrong. The problem was in my storyboard. The textView was bigger than the cell, so I'm guessing it was covering the following cell, and so forth. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problems  happy to help

Comment: Now I have another problem lol. The labels are not showing up now @SahebRoy

Comment: check the label's rect and activate the display debugger to see the label's actual position in runtime.

Comment: Just did that. They don't even show up on there. @SahebRoy

Comment: check the rect of the label and its x and y, it should show up, try clicking on each element and you will get the name of the element and recognise if its the one you are looking for.

Comment: So I did that, but they don't show up while debugging. I added some photos of where they are placed, but when running the app they don't show up @SahebRoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in my storyboard. The UITextView I was using was way too big for it to fit in the tableView, so I'm guessing it was covering the content of the cells and not letting it display it in the app.

Thank you everyone who replied!!